# AWS Compute Optimizer - Lambda Data Unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have opted for the **AWS Compute Optimizer** in order to get recommendations on how to save costs in our infrastructure. As expected, I get recommendations for EC2 instances, Auto Scaling groups and EBS volumes.

However, it fails to show the same for **Lambda functions**, as can be seen from the below screenshot, in spite of active Lambda usage in the account.

[image]

Haven't been able to understand what seems to be missing. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: When did you opt in for aws compute optimiser? sometimes it take 12 hours to give recommendations, also AWS Compute Optimizer analyzes metrics from the past 14 days to generate recommendations, i assume your lambda has been created before 14 days

Comment: added a solution as to why you are not able to see recommendations from compute optimizer

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, I had opted in a few days ago and it could be possible that the lambdas were created before 14 days. But they have been executed several times since the opt-in happened. Shouldn't that suffice for the recommendations to be provided?

Comment: Read my answer, recommendation will only come if they are over provisioned in terms of memory, or compute intensive lambda if there less provisioned, ANy functions that do no fall under any of these, it wont deliver recommendations, which means your lambda functions are running optimally

Comment: compute optimiser wont give `any recommendation for optimum functions`

Answer (score 3):

AWS Compute optimizer is working as it should because:-

According to faq https://aws.amazon.com/compute-optimizer/faqs/#AWS_Lambda_function_recommendations

> Compute Optimizer helps you optimize two categories of Lambda functions. The first category includes Lambda functions that may be over-provisioned in memory sizes. You may consider downsizing the memory sizes of these functions to save costs. The second category includes compute-intensive Lambda functions that may benefit from additional CPU power. You may consider increasing their memory sizes to trigger an equivalent increase in CPU available to these functions and reduce execution time. For functions that do not fall under any of these categories, Compute Optimizer does not deliver recommendations for them.

**For functions that do not fall under any of these categories, Compute Optimizer does not deliver recommendations for them.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since there are >50 lambdas for which we have not performed any sort of memory optimization, I thought I might get a recommendation or 2 at least! I think that there are at least a few lambdas that would fall in either of the two categories described. :)

Comment: Maybe you are thinking that they are not optimized but for optimizer, they are another over-provisioned or less provisioned or another reason that optimiser does not have sufficient data i.e data for last 14 days

Comment: Neither over provisioned  not less provisioned *